# Faking standard input for an XS function

Tags: perl, testing, xs, editline

I'm trying to test a function that reads from standard input by redirecting the standard input to read from a file, more or less as [advised here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432518/perl-testing-an-input-reader)

Here's the script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Term::EditLine qw(CC_EOF);

use v5.14;

my $el = Term::EditLine->new('progname');
$el->set_prompt ('# ');

$el->add_fun ('bye','desc',sub { say "\nbye"; return CC_EOF; });
$el->parse('bind','-e');
$el->parse('bind','exit','bye');

*STDIN = *DATA;

while (defined($_ = $el->gets())) {
  say $_;
}

__DATA__;
goo
gar
exit
```

It's using [`Term::Editline`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::EditLine) which you would have to install first. In this case, instead of reading from the (faked) standard input, it drops me into the prompt. The input is designed so that the last one of them, `exit`, would signal exiting (as indicated in the command above). However, it simply does not take its input from the redirected handle. It might be the case that `gets` is actually a function defined in an XS, but it might be something completely different. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think this _might_ be possible by actually reopening STDIN to the DATA file handle (`open(STDIN, '<&', \*DATA)`) but I can't test r/n. That should have effects on the POSIX level, not just on the PerlIO level. This might still fail if the Term::EditLine module has more complex interactions with the terminal than just reading from STDIN. In that case, testing your software as a separate process with something like Expect could be the easiest approach.

Comment: Try adding the `DATA` handle as input handle to the constructor: `my $el = Term::EditLine->new('progname', \*DATA, \*STDOUT, \*STDERR)`